# Reapplying for a UK visa after refusal for financial reasons

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, ghanaian-citizens

Tax return documents that my husband has are for big contracts he did as far back as 2013. Will these be too old to use to support his self employed status? For filing for tax returns in retrospect, which period should this cover? Since tax return is normally filed end of year will evidence for when the company started in 2013 to 2014 be enough or should it cover up to now - July 2015?

About proportionality? Would you say spending 7,300 GHS on the trip with savings of 25,200 GHS is proportional? If not, what would you suggest and how would changing these figures impact the application. The reason it seems high was due to the depreciation of the cedi at the time (£1 to 6.9 GHS). Now it has improved (£1 to 6 GHS) so can we change it? Would it be better to quote the pound equivalent instead?

Comment: @pnut and Flimzy my husband and I are Ghanaian and he was refused recently on grounds of insufficient funds and intention to return -paragraph 4.2 (a) (e). I have an earlier post titled re-applying for UK visa after refusal explaining the situation in more detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Answer (score 3):

Your husband is submitting his tax returns because he works for cash-in-hand and does not receive salary slips and he does not deposit his salary in the bank.  He should go back far enough to establish that his financial status is sound.  Based upon what you wrote, there is only one tax return available, so he should submit it.  Understand that this is a weak position to be in for a UK visitor application.  They don't like it when somebody works cash-in-hand because the applicant will think it's OK to do that here in the UK.  And a single prior year's tax return is barely admissible as evidence; I would be surprised if the ECO even looked at it.

For your question about proportionality, an exact amount cannot be computed without seeing lots of personal information (which would not be appropriate here); there is no exact figure.  You have asked if a trip that depletes 1/4 - 1/3 of your husband's savings is proportionate. I don't think it is, especially if he has no documented way to replenish it when he returns.  But this is strictly a *guess*.  The ECO will make a *guess* also, that's all anyone can do; but the ECO has the advantage of seeing all your stuff so his guess will be much more informed (and that's what he does for a living).

The rules are pretty clear that there is no minimum amount they need to see in order to apply successfully.  But on the other hand, the applicant's circumstances need to make sense.  Given that your husband has just received his first refusal (where they threw the book at him -- 'a' through 'e') and his financial evidence is decidedly weak and he is  overextending himself financially by depleting his savings, you may wish to wait until things improve or to visit him in Ghana.  I pointed out in an earlier answer that BHC Accra is the most captious and demanding issuing post on the planet. If he receives a second refusal then matters will be worse.

Related question: [Re-applying for a UK visa after getting a refusal due to unexplained deposits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52429/re-applying-for-uk-visit-visa-after-refusal)

Comment: just wanted to clarify that the self employed job is just an aside. He is a salaried worker and has provided evidence of that and the bulk of his savings has from income for his full time employment as a teacher saved over the years.

Comment: @knaa, that's fine. We can both hope that someone else will come along with an answer that's more pleasing for you.  Perhaps today or tomorrow. Give it a few days so everyone will have a chance to answer.